# Removing duplicate application entries in context menus

Tags: shortcut-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove duplicate “Open With” context menu items in Finder.app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10523/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-open-with-context-menu-items-in-finder-app)

I've installed Parallels Desktop 7 and I believe it's the reason I have duplicate application entries. It might not be, but otherwise I'm not sure. Is there a way to remove them?

[image]

Comment: Related questions: [How do I remove duplicate "Open With" context menu items in Finder.app?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10523/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-open-with-context-menu-items-in-finder-app?rq=1), [Why is there a duplicate entry for my TextMate?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9929/why-is-there-a-duplicate-entry-for-my-textmate?rq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.fra‌mework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```