# Repeated applications under Open With Menu

Tags: file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my Mac’s list of “Open with” applications start listing the apps twice and sometimes three times?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68596/why-does-my-macs-list-of-open-with-applications-start-listing-the-apps-twice)

When I right-click on a file and select Open With option, I see many repeated applications:

[image: repeated apps]

How do I get rid of these repeated options?

Comment: Other related questions: [9929](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9929/), [10523](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10523/), [64124](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64124/), [64580](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64580/), [68530](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68530/).

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and type the following

> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user

Then restart or log out and log back in, this should fix the problem.